# WPF - catch exception in Main

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

In the project WPF; I found that if an exception raises in `Main`, it isn't caught because `new App` is executed after the `exception` raised. If the `exception` comes after `new App`, it can be caught.

I wonder that I have to recatch it in `Main` or there is another way to catch it the methods available.

**App.xaml**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        SetupExceptionHandling();
    }

    private void SetupExceptionHandling()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (s, e) =>
        {
            //log
        };

        this.DispatcherUnhandledException += (s, e) =>
        {
            //log
        };

        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (s, e) =>
        {
            //log
        };
    }

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception();
            var app = new App();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //log
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you call `SetupExceptionHandling` in Main instead of App?

Comment: tried but DispatcherUnhandledException is for App

Comment: @kennyzx I updated the question

Comment: Setting up handler for `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` in Main method should be sufficient, as it it is raised for _any_ unhandled exception in _any_ thread. You can keep the other two in the App class.

Comment: There is another way to place the 3 handle in same method?

Answer (score -1):

Create 2 methods:

One is used in `Main` and another in `App`.

It seems ugly but I can't figure out a better way.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        SetupExceptionHandlingInApp();
    }

    private static void SetupExceptionHandlingInMain()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (s, e) =>
        {
            //log
        };

        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (s, e) =>
        {
            //log
        };
    }

    private void SetupExceptionHandlingInApp()
    {            
        this.DispatcherUnhandledException += (s, e) =>
        {
            //log
        };                      

    }

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        SetupExceptionHandlingInMain();
        var app = new App();
        throw new Exception();
    }
```